# Exception when deleting an object in database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

First, sorry for my english. It is not my first langue. I'm trying to remove a data in my database but I receive an exception when `SaveCahnges` is called.

> An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code`

this is a innerException message

> InnerException {"The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint \"FK_dbo.OfferImages_dbo.Offers_Offer_Id\". The conflict occurred in database \"aspnet-LivrETS-20160629111902\", table \"dbo.OfferImages\", column 'Offer_Id'.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."}  System.Exception {System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException}

This is my repository

```
public void DeleteOffer(string[] Ids)
    {
        foreach (string Id in Ids)
        {
            Offer offer = GetOfferBy(Id);
            _db.Offers.Remove(offer);
        }

        _db.SaveChanges();
    }
```

I call this function from my javascript code with AJAX.

My migration is updated but, I have tables in database who are not in my models because I have install a dependance (hangFire) who came  with its tables.

Thanks

Comment: When the exception occurs, go to the InnerException message and copy it in your question.

Comment: I would think that an item could not be deleted if it would break contraints that are not cascading...

Comment: The inner exception outlines the problem, and the FK is named in a way that it is easy to find the source of your problem. Your table (OfferImages) has a foreign key reference to your other table (Offers). You cannot delete  the entry in the Offers table without first deleting the entry or entries in the OfferImages table, with the way your database is currently structured.

Comment: thanks, for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you're trying do delete a row in Offer table, but OfferId is a foreign key of another table (according to the exeption, it is Offer Images).
To remove a row from Offer table, you have to remove all row which contain that offerId in OfferImages first.

But in my opinion, you should add a column called ActiveFlag (bit), to remove the column, you just have to change ActiveFlag to false.